# First material applies but second does not

Tags: materials

The first pin material I created is able to get assigned to the whole pin. The second stripe material I can't get assigned to anything. ​

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: I've switched to Edit mode, selected the whole mesh, selected the Stripes Material in the material list and clicked Assign, and the object changed its color... perhaps I'm missing something in your question, though

Answer (score 2):

In the edit mode select the mesh with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> Box select and then select the material (red) and click on assign material.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried this. Thank you though. I was selecting vertices when I should have been selecting faces.